# Find then Replace Class and text to Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, replace, addclass

Given script find **text** from `.label` *(text1 or any text)*, then it add class `class="text1"` to parent list `<li>` like this: `<li class="text1">`

**Jquery:**

```
$('.label a').each(function() {
  $(this).closest('li').addClass($(this).text());
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="main-id">

<button class="one"></button>  
    <button class="two"></button>  

<ul>

<li> <!--List 1-->
<span class="meta">
<div class="label">
<a href="http://lorem.com">text1</a> <!--This text-->
</div>
</span>
</li>

<li> <!--List 2-->
<span class="meta">
<div class="label">
<a href="http://lorem.com">text2</a> <!--This text-->
</div>
</span>
</li>

</ul>
</div>
```

*By this Script we get Result:*

```
<ul>

<li class="text1"> <!--Got New class to List 1-->
<span class="meta">
<div class="label">
<a href="http://lorem.com">text1</a>
</div>
</span>
</li>

<li class="text2"> <!--Got New class List 2-->
<span class="meta">
<div class="label">
<a href="http://lorem.com">text2</a>
</div>
</span>
</li>

</ul>
```

Please See Example [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7ts8Lcpa/1/) >

*Now* following my question i'm trying to replace Class and Text to Buttons, there have two buttons like `<button class="one"></button>` and `<button class="two"></button>`, now want to place class/text `.text1` (or any class) inside button,
like: `<button class="one text1">text1</li></button>` and 
 `<button class="two text2">text2</li></button>` by same jquery given above.

I have tried this Replace text [script](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-replacetext/examples/replacetext/), but i'm unable to do that. Any suggestion for other way to do this? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: FYI, this isn't valid HTML markup, getting `button` direct descendant of `ul` element and btw, getting `li` as direct child of `button` element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you are going for but you could try something like this.

```
<html>
<body>

    <div id="main-id">
        <button class="one"></button>  
        <button class="two"></button>  

        <ul id="main-list">
            <li>
                <span class="meta">
                    <div class="label">
                        <a href="http://lorem.com">text1</a>
                    </div>
                </span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span class="meta">
                    <div class="label">
                        <a href="http://lorem.com">text2</a>
                    </div>
                </span>
            </li>
        </ul>

    </div>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){

    var btns = ['.one', '.two'];

    $('#main-list li').each(function(k,el){
        // use clone if you don't want to remove original dom element
        var $li = $(el).clone(); 
        var className = $li.find('a').text();

        $li.addClass(className)
            .empty()
            .text(className);

        var $btn = $(btns[k]);
        $btn.append($li);
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, It works, but main HTML block get remove, please see here: https://jsfiddle.net/7ts8Lcpa/2/

Comment: Maybe try jquery clone method?

Comment: Yes, this is great idea.